# Grunt Package Name Output into Jade File

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I wanted to know if it is possible to put the pkg.name and pkg.version into a jade file so I can output a special css file name? I have <% pkg.name %>-<% pkg.version %>.css in the jade but it is only outputting just that, and is not outputting the name and version from the package.json file. Is this possible to do?

Comment: are you compiling the jade with grunt?

Answer (score 0):

In your Gruntfile.js

```
jade: {
    compile: {
      options: {
        pretty: true,
        data: {name: '<%= pkg.name %>', version: '<%= pkg.version %>'}
```

In your jade template

```
p Package: #{name} Version: #{version}.
```